# Excel Import from S3 Buckets

Tags: c#, excel, amazon-s3

I am publishing Asp.Net application to AWS. One of the requirements are to read data from Excel files and then upload it into Ms-SQL Server. The excel files are successfully uploaded to S3 Buckets. Now, I want to load data from Excel files (saved into S3 buckets) into Dataset. If I try to access these files via URL, they start downloading. Is there any way to read excel files from S3 URL and load them into Dataset temporarily? Any suggestions, how this can be done?

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: where are you blocked ? you don't know how to read excel file ? you don't know how to access s3 files ? please specify what you've done and where you are stopped

Comment: @FrédéricHenri - How to read Excel files from URL because once you try to access URL, it starts downloading

Comment: I'll be happy to be wrong - but you cannot read s3 files remotely, there's no API for that so you need to get the object and process it once you download it

Comment: I have uploaded images as well which can be easily accessed via URLs in assigned to them using S3 Buckets. Now, one requirement is to read content from excel files and load into the dataset and these excel files reside on S3 and I cannot read these files via URL because if I hit URL, it starts downloading. I don't know what other options are available and how

Comment: why do you down vote ? I gave you an option to get the file from s3 so you can process it - I think you should really re-edit your questions with sample of what you have then we can work on YOUR code, until then all you get will be samples from doc

Comment: every object in s3 bucket has been assigned a url which is being used to access that. I am accessing images via this url. If I try to access the excel files in the same way, then its not working, instead the excel files are downloading (try to put a url in browser's address bar for excel file). Now, my problem is to read the content from excel file stored in S3 bucket. Hope this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118794/discussion-between-anil-c-and-frederic-henri).

Comment: you can't read the content from s3 - s3 does not work like a standard hard drive, there's no IO operation, you can put content and get content, so yes you will download your object (either through s3 API as my answer or from URL if you have right policy) and you will treat files locally once downloaded

Comment: Download to a temporary file, use OLE or ADO to read the data into a .NET record-set, and then upload to SQL server.  These are pretty standard operations in C#.

Comment: @david25272 this is a web application, if I download the file, it will be saved onto client's machine and web application cannot access a location on client's machine, so, its not possible